# How the concept described below can be desined in the C++14?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, visual-c++, c++14

I have to develop a C++ framework for an automation engine, which is able to run arbitrary user actions (C++ classes with the abstract method Execute()) in succession. Besides the usual input and output parameters, these actions have access to a common data structure, which serves as a global environment or context for all actions. My question is about this data structure.

The context plays role of a common storage, to which any action can put a piece of data, and later some other action can take this data and use it. So that, this context should behave as a container of named elements of different types, unknown at design time. The elements can be a simple integer, a string or a pointer to a class. Their exact type is unknown until runtime. And of course, when the context is destroyed, it should destroy all its elements.

Advice regarding std::any is useful, but does not solve the problem. std::any gives a convenient way to store data internally, but I do not want std::any in the interface. That is, I would like that one action could place its data into the storage with a call like

```
MyType* pObj1 = new MyType(...);    // MyType is the user's class
pContext->addData("UniqueName", pObj1);
```

and the other action later could access this data with a call like

```
MyType* pObj1 = pContext->getData("UniqueName");
```

Is there a way to implement such a concept in the modern C++?

Comment: [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) or [`std::any`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, Encouragingly, but these classes are implemented only since C++17, while I have C++14 (as it is pointed in the question).

Comment: Then use Boost and their Boost equivalents?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes, std::any can be a good idea; I'll try to find its implementation and use it. Thank you!

Comment: For the boost averse, a single-header C++11 `std::variant` from the guy that wrote the clang implementation: https://github.com/mpark/variant . Similar for `std::any` - https://github.com/martinmoene/any-lite .

Comment: Would you expect `getData(keyName)` to return an object of the appropriate type? Or would you expect the client code to cast it back to what it expects the result should be? When you say the exact type is unknown until runtime, do you really mean runtime, or you mean that the library doesn't know  the types, but users of the class do know the type at design time?

Comment: @divinas When the object was put in, I had information about its exact type. So theoretically, I could use this information to return the exact type from the call to getData(keyName). This is no doubt the preferred behavior. But I do not know how to implement this...

Comment: @divinas, And yes, the library doesn't know the types, but users of the class do know the type at design time.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can not do a version of getData that returns the correct type, for an arbitrary type. C++ is a statically typed language, and a function can return a value of only a single type. You could have a template, but templates are resolved compile time. Maybe there's some trick that I'm not thinking of. I have a good idea of how you can do a `getData<Type>(keyName)`. If you're interested in that, I can write an answer with it

Comment: @divinas, I also came to the conclusion, that both `putData` and `getData` methods must be templates. Templates can help, because, as you correctly noted, users of the class do know the type of their data at compile time. And of course, I appreciate any good idea that will direct me to a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, in game dev, this concept is commonly called a 'blackboard' (I'm sure other domains use the same pattern - maybe under a different name).

In essence, this is just a simple key-value map.

What a lot of games do is to have `template <typename... Types> class Blackboard`. The blackboard internally stores a tuple of maps, one per type that would be stored in a given template instantiation of the blackboard. That way, the author of the library doesn't know about all possible stored classes, but the user does and defines the blackboard with all types they would need, and you avoid  the need for dynamic allocation of the backing types.

From your question, I assume that you do not want such an implementation, and want to keep а single blackboard instance that will store all possible types. You also want values to be destroyed when the blackboard instance is destroyed.

I opted to do a generic blackboard implementation, that is move-only, and can store `unique_ptr`. To do that, I have done a bit of reinventing of the wheel, and made a simplified version of an `any` (called `Handle` in my implementation), that is usable for movable only types (`std::any` can not store `unique_ptr`, as it requires that stored types are copy construct able). **NB! This is a naive and simplistic implementation, many optimizations can be made**

This means that the blackboard itself is **not responsible for freeing any memory**, but the user can provide a `unique_ptr` (or even, `shared_ptr`) if they want the blackboard to own the variables.

### C++ Blackboard Code

```
class Blackboard
{
private:
    struct IHandle
    {
        virtual ~IHandle() = default;
    };
    template <typename T>
    struct Handle : public IHandle
    {
        Handle(T data)
            : m_Data(std::move(data))
        {
        }
        T m_Data;
        T* get()
        {
            return &m_Data;
        }
    };

public:
    template<typename T>
    void AddData(const std::string& key, T object)
    {
        m_Map[key] = std::make_unique<Handle<T>>(Handle<T>(std::move(object)));
    }

    template<typename T>
    T* GetData(const std::string& key)
    {
        auto it = m_Map.find(key);
        if (it != m_Map.end())
        {
            if (auto* handle = dynamic_cast<Handle<T>*>(it->second.get()))
            {
                return handle->get();
            }
        }
    return nullptr;
    }
private:
    std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<IHandle>> m_Map;
};
```

### Example

```
struct MyType
{
    ~MyType() { std::cout << "~MyType()"; }
};
int main()
{
    Blackboard b;
    b.AddData("someVar", 7);
    int* someVar = b.GetData<int>("someVar");
    std::cout << "*someVar as int: " << *someVar << std::endl;
    *someVar = 88; 

    b.AddData("otherVar", std::make_unique<int>(99));
    std::cout << "*someVar after modifying, as int: " <<*(b.GetData<int>("someVar")) << std::endl;

    std::unique_ptr<int>* otherVar = b.GetData<std::unique_ptr<int>>("otherVar");
    std::cout << "*otherVar->get() as unique_ptr<int>: " << *(otherVar->get()) << std::endl;

    std::cout << "otherVar as int: " << b.GetData<int>("otherVar") << std::endl;
    //Blackboard blackboardCopy{ b }; //Does not compile
    Blackboard movedBB{ std::move(b) }; //compiles fine, b now does not contain anything
    movedBB.AddData("MyTypeVar", std::make_unique<MyType>());

    //Because "MyTypeVar" is a unique_ptr<MyType>, as soon as movedBB goes out of scope
    //MyType's dtor will be called
}
```

Output on my computer:

> *someVar as int: 7
>
> *someVar after modifying through int*, as int: 88
>
> *otherVar->get() as unique_ptr: 99
>
> otherVar as int: 00000000
>
> ~MyType()

### Owning memory

If you want to make the blackboard own memory, it is easy to make some template magic to wrap pointer types inside a `unique_ptr` before storing them, and return `unique_ptr.get()` when `getData()` is called. I personally dislike this approach for design reasons, as it makes the Blackboard share more than one responsibility.

### Using `std::any`

You can swap out my poor `Handle` implementation for `std::any`.To do that, instead of storing `unique_ptr<IHandle>` inside the map, just store `std::any`. Also swap the `dynamic_cast` for `std::any_cast`. The only downside to doing that is that you can no longer store move only types in the Blackboard, but on the other hand you can copy the blackboard around freely. You also gain all optimizations that the standard library has made for `std::any`.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer seems to give me exactly what I need. The same idea occurred to me too (in the version with std::any). I did not understand, however, one place in your code. In the constructor of the `Handle` class you move the input parameter: `Handle(T data) : m_Data(std::move(data)) {}`. And when you call this constructor inside `AddData` method, you move the argument again: `Handle<T>(std::move(object))`. Why it is needed to move twice?

Comment: As i mentioned, the code is very basic. It performs a lot of useless copies and moves for the sake of simplicity. As i take the template parameter by value, it will be copied via either the copy constructor or move constructor. If `T` is a move-only type (ex. std::unique_ptr), it can not be copied with a copy constructor, so i call `std::move` to cast it to an rvalue so that the move copy ctor is invoked.

A more solid and robust implementation would implement perfect forwarding for `AddData` and the `Handle` constructors, to avoid the useless moves/copies.

Comment: Said in a different way: in `AddData`, `object` is an lvalue (it has a name). In the `Handle<T>` constructor, `data` is an lvalue as well (again, has a name). to be able to invoke the move c-tor of `T`, those need to be rvalues, so I must do a cast to rvalue. Remember: `std::move` does not move anything, it just performs a cast to rvalue. During overload resolution, a function that accepts an rvalue reference, (in our case, move ctor) will be preferred, and this function is responsible for doing the actual move part.